# Show latest status count of all members group by category in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I am working with a SQL Server database. I want to show IN/OUT status count of members by category. There are any number of records for each member but I want to get latest status of each unique member within specified datetime.I want to show reports like how many MLR Sailers are IN & how many out within specified datetime. Same for other categories. As i mention each member has multiple status within day but want to get his current status & increase count in respective category.

Records :

| SrNo | MemberID | Name | Department | Category | Status | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | Surya | My Department | Inliving Junior Sailor | OUT | 28-Jun-21 3:15:33 PM |
| 2 | 1 | Admin | Test dept | MLR Sailor | OUT | 28-Jun-21 3:24:38 PM |
| 3 | 1 | Admin | Test dept | MLR Sailor | IN | 28-Jun-21 3:29:20 PM |
| 4 | 3 | Aarohi | My Department | Inliving Senior Sailor | IN | 28-Jun-21 6:22:09 PM |
| 5 | 1 | Admin | Test dept | MLR Sailor | IN | 28-Jun-21 6:22:40 PM |
| 6 | 2 | Surya | My Department | Inliving Junior Sailor | OUT | 28-Jun-21 6:22:48 PM |
| 7 | 4 | Vishal | My Department | MLR Sailor | OUT | 28-Jun-21 6:22:59 PM |
| 8 | 4 | Vishal | My Department | MLR Sailor | IN | 28-Jun-21 6:23:08 PM |
| 9 | 1 | Admin | Test dept | MLR Sailor | IN | 28-Jun-21 6:23:16 PM |
| 10 | 4 | Vishal | My Department | MLR Sailor | IN | 28-Jun-21 6:23:29 PM |
| 11 | 1 | Admin | Test dept | MLR Sailor | IN | 28-Jun-21 6:23:31 PM |
| 12 | 3 | Aarohi | My Department | Inliving Senior Sailor | IN | 28-Jun-21 6:23:34 PM |
| 13 | 3 | Aarohi | My Department | Inliving Senior Sailor | IN | 28-Jun-21 6:23:36 PM |
| 14 | 3 | Aarohi | My Department | Inliving Senior Sailor | OU | 28-Jun-21 6:23:36 PM |
| 15 | 4 | Vishal | My Department | MLR Sailor | IN | 28-Jun-21 6:23:37 PM |
| 16 | 2 | Surya | My Department | Inliving Junior Sailor | IN | 28-Jun-21 6:23:39 PM |
| 17 | 4 | Vishal | My Department | MLR Sailor | OUT | 28-Jun-21 6:23:40 PM |

Required OUTPUT

| Category | IN | OUT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Inliving Junior Sailor | 0 | 1 |
| MLR Sailor | 1 | 1 |
| Inliving Senior Sailor | 0 | 1 |

Comment: Unfortunately your sample data isn't particularly consumable. Take the time to post in as DDL and DML statements. Also explain the problem you're trying to solve and don't forget to include your attempts (and details of why they didn't work).

Comment: can you explain how you achieve the result set from above data ?

Comment: i want to show category wise In Out member count.. i tied group by clause but haven't got expected result.

Failed queries : 

"Select c.Category,trans.Status from FM_Transaction trans inner join  M_Member m on trans.MemberID=m.MemberID Left Outer join M_Category c on m.CateID=c.CategoryID where trans.IsActive = 1  group by c.Category,trans.Status"

GOT Result like below :
_____________________________
Inliving Junior Sailor IN        
Inliving Junior Sailor OUT       
MLR Sailor IN        
MLR Sailor OUT

Comment: `Select trans.Category,count(trans.MemberID) as count,trans.Status from (select e.MemberID, trans.Time_second,trans.Status,c.Category
from (select trans.*,
             row_number() over (partition by trans.MemberID order by trans.Time_second desc) as seqnum
      from FM_Transaction trans
     ) trans join M_Member e
  Left Outer join M_Category c on e.CateID=c.CategoryID
     on e.MemberID = trans.MemberID 
where trans.seqnum = 1 and trans.IsActive = 1  And trans.Time_second between '27-Jun-2021 12:00:01 AM' And '29-Jun-2021 11:25:45 AM') trans group by trans.Category,trans.Status`